# Partial id Xpath query returns null

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have element with `ID=Mscrm.BasicHomeTab.New.NewRecord`

if I use following query - I successfully get the element

`FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Mscrm.BasicHomeTab.New.NewRec‌​ord']"))`

but if I try to get element by partial ID it fails

`FindElement(By.XPath("//*[ends-with(@id,'NewRecord')]"))`

What's wrong with the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply an [ends-with CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
By.cssSelector("[id$=NewRecord]")
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes, css selector is working. But I don't want to mix css and xpath approach in one test

Answer (score 1):

`Selenium` (for now) supports `XPath 1.0` version only, while `ends-with()` function is from `XPath 2.0`.

You can try to use `contains()` instead as

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id,'NewRecord')]"))
```

to match `id` by partial substring

or

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('NewRecord') +1) = 'NewRecord']"))
```

as similar to `ends-with()`

Comment: @algot , is there any reason for deaccepting answer? Do you want me to improve my solution?